# drupal page.tpl.php content variable?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

The print $content statement in page.tpl.php . I want to alter it but I can't figure out what/where is the source of the $content variable in page.tpl.php  file.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

the drupal version is 6,

Comment: Can you clarify if you are asking about changing the $content variable itself or are you asking about manipulating the various fields within the $content variable (such as title, body, etc)?

Comment: changing the $content variable itself .thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chx's answer is correct. This is just a longer explanation.

$content depends on the URL or more precisely the region that calls the variable.
The URL could be something like node/10, taxonomy/term/1, etc. Each of these paths is associated with menu entry which has a callback function that generates the value of $content.

Take a look at the API docs for more info. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_content/6

Answer (score 2):

This is the return value of `menu_execute_active_handler()`. You can't change it in Drupal 6. You need Drupal 7 `hook_page_alter()` for that. Now, preprocess helps a little, see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6

Comment: thanks for your reply, but in the index.php,there is the code ' require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);' then in the bootstrap.inc' i can't find the menu_execute_active_handler() defined. why?

$return = menu_execute_active_handler();

Answer (score 0):

The ConTemplate module might provide the sort of control over $content that you are looking for. http://drupal.org/project/contemplate